# How to remove a shape without using background(255);

Tags: java, function, processing

I am trying to make the drawRedlines function appear and disappear inside the mousePressed function and mouseReleased function. I have tried using background(255); in my mouseReleased but it also removes my crossBars function for some reason. I tried changing the cords for the redLine rect's to 0 but it still is in the same position when I release the mouse.

```java
final int NUM_LINES = 15;
final int LINE_THICK = 20;
final int CONVERGE_VERTICAL_OFFSET = 175;
final int CONVERGE_VERTICAL_OFFSET2 = 100;

int capSize = 20;
int width = 500;
int height = 500;
int x1 = 30;
int crossWidth = width - (30*2);
int y1 = height - 20;
int crossHeight = 20;
int capX = x1;
int capY = y1 + crossHeight/2;
int capX2 = width - x1;
int diffY = 60;
int diffX = 10;
int redLinex = 145;
int redLinex2 = 350;
int redLiney = 0;
int redlineHeight = height;
int redlineWidth = 5;

void setup(){
    size(500,500);
    drawConvergingvertical();
    horizontalCross();
    drawYellowlines();
}

void draw(){
}

void mousePressed(){
    drawRedlines();
}

void mouseReleased(){
    drawConvergingvertical();
    horizontalCross();
    drawYellowlines();
}

void horizontalCross(){
    for(int rows = 0; rows < NUM_LINES; rows++){
        //println(rows, capX, capX2); Used this to Debug;
        drawCrossbars();
        y1 = y1 - diffY;
        capY = capY - diffY - 1;
        x1 = x1 + diffX;
        capX = capX + diffX;
        crossWidth = crossWidth - diffX*2;
        capX2 = capX2 - diffX;
        crossHeight = crossHeight - 2;
        capSize = capSize - 2;
    }
}

void drawCrossbars(){
    rect(x1,y1,crossWidth,crossHeight);
    ellipse(capX,capY,capSize,capSize);
    ellipse(capX2,capY,capSize,capSize);
}

void drawConvergingvertical(){
    fill(0);
    stroke(0);
    quad(width/2-CONVERGE_VERTICAL_OFFSET,height,width/2-CONVERGE_VERTICAL_OFFSET2,0,width/2-CONVERGE_VERTICAL_OFFSET2+LINE_THICK,0,width/2-CONVERGE_VERTICAL_OFFSET+LINE_THICK,height);
    quad(width/2+CONVERGE_VERTICAL_OFFSET,height,width/2+CONVERGE_VERTICAL_OFFSET2,0,width/2+CONVERGE_VERTICAL_OFFSET2-LINE_THICK,0,width/2+CONVERGE_VERTICAL_OFFSET-LINE_THICK,height);
}

void drawYellowlines(){
    fill(255,255,0);
    stroke(255,255,0);
    rect(150, height - 100, 200, 10);
    rect(150, 100, 200, 10);
}

void drawRedlines(){
    redLinex = 145;
    redLinex2 = 350;
    redLiney = 0;
    redlineHeight = height;
    redlineWidth = 5;
    fill(255,0,0);
    stroke(255,0,0);
    rect(redLinex,redLiney,redlineWidth,redlineHeight);
    rect(redLinex2,redLiney,redlineWidth,redlineHeight);
}
```

Comment: *"How to remove a shape without using background(255);"* - Not at all. You cant "remove" something what is drawn in the window. All you can do is to draw something different, what covers the shape. `background` doesn't remove anything. It just draws an uniform color in the entire window.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I'm trying to "clear" the drawRedLines function when the mouse is released. Is there a way to make them only appear during mousePressed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to remove a shape without using background(255); [...]

Not at all. You cant "remove" something what is drawn in the window. All you can do is to draw something different, what covers the shape. `background` doesn't remove anything. It just draws an uniform color in the entire window.
You've to redraw the entire scene in `draw()`.

Use the built-in variable `mousePressed` to identify if the mouse is pressed and call `drawRedlines()` dependent on the state of the variable. Furthermore you've to reset the state of some variables in in every frame:

```java
void draw() {

    capSize = 20;
    x1 = 30;
    crossWidth = width - (30*2);
    y1 = height - 20;
    crossHeight = 20;
    capX = x1;
    capY = y1 + crossHeight/2;
    capX2 = width - x1;
    diffY = 60;
    diffX = 10;
    redLinex = 145;
    redLinex2 = 350;
    redLiney = 0;
    redlineHeight = height;
    redlineWidth = 5;

    background(200);
    drawConvergingvertical();
    horizontalCross();
    drawYellowlines();
    if (mousePressed) {
        drawRedlines();
    }
}
```

Note, it is not necessary to draw anything in the mouse callback functions `mousePressed` respectively `mouseReleased`.

```java
void mousePressed(){
}

void mouseReleased(){
}
```

---

Side note: Remove declaration of the variables [`width`](https://processing.org/reference/width.html) and [`height`](https://processing.org/reference/height.html) from your code. This are built-in variables, so it is not necessary to declare them at all, especially since the dependent variables are set in `draw`.

<s>`int width = 500;`</s>
<s>`int height = 500;`</s>

Answer (score 0):

The `draw()` method is a loop. If you draw your stuff inside that loop, you can update it in real time. I modified your loop a little bit so the red lines appears only while the left mouse button si down:

```
final int NUM_LINES = 15;
final int LINE_THICK = 20;
final int CONVERGE_VERTICAL_OFFSET = 175;
final int CONVERGE_VERTICAL_OFFSET2 = 100;

int capSize = 20;
int width = 500;
int height = 500;
int x1 = 30;
int crossWidth = width - (30*2);
int y1 = height - 20;
int crossHeight = 20;
int capX = x1;
int capY = y1 + crossHeight/2;
int capX2 = width - x1;
int diffY = 60;
int diffX = 10;
int redLinex = 145;
int redLinex2 = 350;
int redLiney = 0;
int redlineHeight = height;
int redlineWidth = 5;

boolean redLineVisible = false;

void setup(){
  size(500,500);
  //drawConvergingvertical();
  //horizontalCross();
  //drawYellowlines();
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  drawConvergingvertical();
  horizontalCross();
  drawYellowlines();
  drawRedlines();
}

void mousePressed(){
  //drawRedlines();
  redLineVisible = true;
}

void mouseReleased(){
  //drawConvergingvertical();
  //horizontalCross();
  //drawYellowlines();
  //drawRedlines();
  redLineVisible = false;
}




void horizontalCross(){
  for(int rows = 0; rows < NUM_LINES; rows++){
    //println(rows, capX, capX2); Used this to Debug;
    drawCrossbars();
    y1 = y1 - diffY;
    capY = capY - diffY - 1;
    x1 = x1 + diffX;
    capX = capX + diffX;
    crossWidth = crossWidth - diffX*2;
    capX2 = capX2 - diffX;
    crossHeight = crossHeight - 2;
    capSize = capSize - 2;
  }
}

void drawCrossbars(){
  rect(x1,y1,crossWidth,crossHeight);
  ellipse(capX,capY,capSize,capSize);
  ellipse(capX2,capY,capSize,capSize);
}

void drawConvergingvertical(){
  fill(0);
  stroke(0);
  quad(width/2-CONVERGE_VERTICAL_OFFSET,height,width/2-CONVERGE_VERTICAL_OFFSET2,0,width/2-CONVERGE_VERTICAL_OFFSET2+LINE_THICK,0,width/2-CONVERGE_VERTICAL_OFFSET+LINE_THICK,height);
  quad(width/2+CONVERGE_VERTICAL_OFFSET,height,width/2+CONVERGE_VERTICAL_OFFSET2,0,width/2+CONVERGE_VERTICAL_OFFSET2-LINE_THICK,0,width/2+CONVERGE_VERTICAL_OFFSET-LINE_THICK,height);
}

void drawYellowlines(){
  fill(255,255,0);
  stroke(255,255,0);
  rect(150, height - 100, 200, 10);
  rect(150, 100, 200, 10);
}

void drawRedlines(){
  if (redLineVisible) {
    redLinex = 145;
    redLinex2 = 350;
    redLiney = 0;
    redlineHeight = height;
    redlineWidth = 5;
    fill(255,0,0);
    stroke(255,0,0);
    rect(redLinex,redLiney,redlineWidth,redlineHeight);
    rect(redLinex2,redLiney,redlineWidth,redlineHeight);
  }
}
```

Have fun.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, however if you remove the background command in draw then run, thats how the code is supposed to look. And for some reason when I call background(whatever); it paints over my crossBar function.

Comment: The trick with draw() is that it must be able to draw everything every time you call it. You'll have to make it so your "initial" conditions - which drew those lines first - are met at every iteration of the draw loop.